# TableView does not register clicks in Swift & custom cells do not display

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, uitableview

I'm trying to use tableViews for the first time but I am running into an issue. When I run my program containing the code below, clicking on a cell is not registered. In addition, my custom cells (image below as well) do not display uniquely either. My code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    print("Success!") 
}
```

Declaring information:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //print(numApplications)
    if numApplications != 0 {

    }
    //print("2nd?")
    //print(numApplications)
    if numApplications < 7 {
        return 7
    }
    else {
        return numApplications
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tableView.rowHeight = 85
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    //print(indexPath.row)
    //print(applications.count)
    if indexPath.row < applications.count {
        cell.textLabel?.text = applications[indexPath.row].msg
    }
    return cell
}
```

[image: My cell]

[image: Cell when run]

Comment: Be aware that in `numberOfRows` you use `numApplications` but in `cellForRow` it's `applications`. This will most likely cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CellName
```

Where `CellName` is your class that you set for the prototype cell in IB with identifier `cell`

Comment: When I do this, it still does not identify if a cell has been clicked. My custom cell does appear, but only when that specific cell has been selected. Why?